# How can I read a json webhook from mixpanel using Zapier?

Tags: mixpanel, zapier

I catch a webhook from mixpanel. The payload includes all the people properties and is formatted in a json object. So far so good. Unfortunately it seems, that I can´t access the properties values I need to.

I have played around with formatter and the coding feature of zapier. I couldn´t make it work.

Help is much appreciated.

Best

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [attempts made so far](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your **desired result** is? For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any code to make it work.

Type 'users' in '**Pick off a Child Key**'. (Trigger > Edit Options)

Then you'll have access to the properties values.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly fine!